# Why do I see the ASCII symbols in Notepad++?

Tags: hex, notepad++, ascii

(I am new with this) I see these weird black text-boxes and, as far as I know, they are ascii symbols, but I don't know how to see it in a "normal" view, if possible. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify if your "text" is equivalent to the image you reference or not. If so, the linked question already has a good [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/271889) and "normal" view would be in a terminal that renders the escapes as color or other formatting. If not, please show your own "text". Also, why is the question tagged XML?

Comment: Because that's what's in the file?

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit hard to follow your link, I included the screenshot in your question. The `ESC` indicates a non-printable character. In this case it is the Escape character (ASCII 27), which from the screen shot appears to be part of escape sequences to change text color.

Unfortunately, Notepad++ does not have the means to render them as intended. One option is that you select one and find/replace with nothing. If you want to get rid of not only the ESC but also its associated "parameters" you can use this regular expression to find and replace them

```
\x1b[^m]*m
```